# VS2017 Test Explorer shows "SpecFlow Evaluation"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit, specflow

I followed the steps from Specflow Getting Started but the Test Explorer in VS2017 shows only "SpecFlow Evaluation" instead of the tests.

https://specflow.org/getting-started/

[image]

Here is the Test Output window:

*Unable to fetch symbols for class: ...SpecRun Evaluation
Unable to fetch source Information for test method: ...::SpecRun Evaluation.Execution delay for SpecRun evaluation mode contained in project: ...*

**Update: I installed a Trial license key for SpecFlow+ and now the Test Explorer shows no tests at all, not even "SpecFlow Evaluation".**

Comment: Do you have `Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool` set to `False` in Tools --> Options --> SpecFlow in Visual Studio?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes I did

Comment: Are the feature.cs files being generated once you build the solution?

Comment: No, there is no feature.cs file. I installed SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, that should generate the cs file, right?

Comment: You are using NUnit. You will need the proper NUnit adaptors installed so Visual Studio can pick up those tests.

Comment: Probably this NuGet package: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter

Comment: I have installed the NUnit VSIX adapters in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you post which NuGet packages you have installed?

Comment: I just installed the NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet package but it didn't help.

Comment: You'll need to build the solution again.

Comment: I built the solution after installing the NuGet package.

Comment: I found here something interesting: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild

At Known Issues: Code-behind files not generating at compile time

Comment: So I just checked on the file system and the feature.cs file was indeed there, it was just not added in the solution. I added the file in the project, built again but the SpecFlow test is still not appearing in the Test Explorer.

Comment: The problem was that the feature.cs was missing in the project like @GregBurghardt said, I also needed the NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet package and I had the wrong runner "SpecRun.SpecFlow", I added the runner for NUnit "SpecFlow.NUnit" and now the tests appear in the Test Explorer.

Comment: You should not need to include the feature.cs files anymore in the solution.

Comment: If I remove the feature.cs file from the project then the tests don't appear in the Test Explorer.